# Django model based on queryset rather than table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model called `Event` and a viewset called `UserEventViewSet` that defines the following method:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return (
        Event.objects.select_related(
            'user',
        ).values(
            'user_id', 
            'type'
        ).annotate(
            count=Count("*"),
            user=JSONObject(
                id=F("event__user__id"),
                first_name=F("event__user__first_name"),
                last_name=F("event__user__last_name"),
            ),
        )
    )
```

This works but it seems less than ideal. As you can see here we are doing the work of the serializer in the viewset.

I think it might be better to move part of this queryset into a manager and attach it to a `UserEvent` model. Then I would hope I could define relations in the model and use a nested serializer for the user data.

I'm not sure how to do it, or if it is even possible.

Comment: Try moving the JSONObject before `.values(...)` so it wont appear in the aggregation. I'm assuming that's what you want? Or add those related fields to the serializer with something like `first_name = serializers.CharField(source="event__user__first_name")` for each. id, first_name, and last_name would need to go in their own serializer to get the nested object structure.

Comment: I really don't see how this has any bearing on my question.

Comment: You want your serializer to serialize a related field right? You do that with the `source` argument.

Comment: Have you seen [Serializer relations | Nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) in DRF docs? What happens if you add `Count` to the queryset there?